# Npm packages written in typescript does not get built in projects

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I've created a small package with typescript. It's a simple console log file like this:

src/index.ts

```
console.log('Hello, World!')
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

I've published it into npmjs.com

```
npm publish
```

I can install that package in a node project. But when I go to node_modules folders and find my project there, I see that, only my ts files exists. It is not built as js files. How can I manage to install (or properly publish) this package?

Comment: Did you run build before publishing?

Comment: Assuming you *did* build before publishing, you need to specify what directories to include with the `files` property in `package.json`. By default it uses the `.gitignore` list to figure out what not to include.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `"rootDir": "src"`, to your tsconfig and then run `yarn build` and then `npm publish`. If you want to control what will be sent to npm, use the `files` property in package.json https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#files

Answer (score 0):

Before publishing the library, you must compile it using the:

```bash
tsc
```

After that, your module can be imported in a third-party project